# InitContainer run a Python command

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, containers

I need to run a `pip install` command in an initcontainer. I´m using the `python:3.9-slim-buster` [image](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/6a2c0f48f011aa279a0c9190725fc84a220460bc/3.9/buster/slim/Dockerfile).

I created the following code, however I get the following error:

*/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip install moduleexample*

**Code:**

```
        spec:
          volumes:
          - name: agent-volume
            emptyDir: {}
          initContainers:
          - name: dd-apm-init
            image: python:3.9-slim-buster
            command: ["python3", "-m", "pip install moduleexample"]
            resources: {}
            volumeMounts:
            - name: agent-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Any suggestions?

================================================================
**UPDATE**:

`Pip Install` works with image `python:3.8-slim-buster`.

It seems that for 3.9 pip is being installed in `site-packages`, while it is not included in default `sys.path`.

When I try to run it from `site-packages`. I get an Access is denied error.

Comment: Why exactly do you need an init container for `pip` commands? Your actual Python app container should _already have_ all its dependencies

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I need a container to install an Agent to monitor the Python App

Comment: Your Python app runs in its own container, right? If so, why can you not modify its image to install your Datadog APM agent?

Comment: `pip install` seems to work fine for 3.9... `docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint=bash python:3.9-slim-buster -c 'pip'` shows the help text, as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the whole command:

```
 ["python3", "-m", "pip", "install", "moduleexample"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a similar error: `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: Well that's maybe because the core image  doesn't contain the `python-pip` package. I'd suggest creating a Dockerfile and installing `pip` first and then the package manually. Use `apt-get -y install python3-pip`.

Comment: `python:3.9-slim-buster` does contain `pip`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes `python:3.9-slim-buster` does contain pip, but it is not included in default `sys.path`. When I run it from `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`i get an Access Denied error :(

Comment: @Cabesa92, would adding `--user` flag help then?

Answer (score 0):

You have given the command in the wrong format. It should be something like this -

```
spec:
      volumes:
      - name: agent-volume
        emptyDir: {}
      initContainers:
      - name: dd-apm-init
        image: python:3.9-slim-buster
        command: ["python3", "-m", "pip", "install", "moduleexample"]
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - name: agent-volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Hope this would resolve the issue for you!

Comment: Thanks, but I get a similar error: `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: Try this - ["python3", "-m", "pip3", "install", "moduleexample"]

Comment: same issue  `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip3`

Comment: @KavishBaghel `pip3` is definiitely not a module. Did you mean `command: ["pip3", "install", "somemodule"]`?